# What type of fitting/adapter for 3/8" NGL from wall valve to 1/2" auto shutoff valve (gas dryer installation)

Tags: dryer, natural-gas

[Here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-5-ft-Gas-Dryer-Connector-Kit-with-Auto-Shut-Off-CA-PM15X118/206279631) is the gas line kit I bought for my dryer.

Below is my gas line from the wall. Additional photos include the OD of the threads and ID of the cap

[image: Shutoff valve at wall]
[image: OD valve]
[image: ID valve cap]

I would like to use the "½-inch MIP auto shut-off valve" pictured below.

[image: Shut Off Valve1]
[image: Shut Off valve ID]
[image: Shut Off valve no internal threading]

What adapter or fitting do I need to go from the flanged outlet at the wall to the "½-inch MIP auto shut-off valve" from the install kit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some photos might help

Comment: @RohitGupta Photos have been added.

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being to visit a home depot in person to get the correct sized kit. The one with the correct size wasn't on their website which is how I originally bought the item

Comment: Something to be said for brick n' mortar.